# Store Metadata doesn't work as expected

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm trying to set a property to a store using the extJS metaData feature.

My JSON response looks like this:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "User": {
                "id": "1",
                "username": "julian",
                "firstname": "Julian",
            }
        }
    ],
    "success": true,
    "metaData": {
        "displayField": "username"
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to output the displayField in my store's load event.
Here's my store:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'AM.model.User',
    autoLoad:false,
    displayField: null,
    listeners:{
        load:function (store) {
            console.log(store.displayField);
        }
    },
    proxy:{
    type:'ajax',
        api:{
            read:BASE_PATH + 'users/index',
            create:BASE_PATH + 'users/edit',
            update:BASE_PATH + 'users/edit',
        destroy:BASE_PATH + 'users/remove'
        },
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            root:'data',
            record:'User',
            messageProperty:"code"
        },
        writer:{
            type:'json',
            writeAllFields:true
        }
    }
});
```

console.log() outputs null

UPDATE:

`store.proxy.reader.displayField` holds the displayField with proper data. But it doesn't really makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through ExtJs source code I think meteData should be inside your `data` array. Do you have control over the server side? Try to put it there, see if client will recognize it.

Comment: This is wrong i guess.
I debugged myself to Json.js Line 203 where ExtJS checks for metaData.
`data` in this case is the full response object.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I never used it myself. Just looked at the code. So is anything getting inside onMetaChange?

Comment: Yeah, my metadata gets applied to `this`.
But it looks like `this` is 'Ext.data.reader.Json'.
Please see also my edited question.

Comment: Then you either need to get it from Reader or rewrite standard reader to apply it to your store.

Comment: interesting, i thought metaData was dropped from the framework in 4 - at least it's not in the docs.